# Distribute doesn't work xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[vs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUa3Y.png)  I created an android application tested and it was all right I did the application archive and also did it correctly, however after that when I click the button distribute the window containing the options "Ad-Hoc" and "Google Play" does not appear to continue the process further.
Can anyone tell me what the problem would be?
And taking that part that distributes it I could publish the application without problems since the .apk folder was normally generated in the archive process?

Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Try restarting your vs and system

Comment: G.hakim It doesn't' work.

Comment: The Microsoft team is working on a fix for this issue (mentioned in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1372)). As in blizzeron's answer, the team's local testing indicates that the issue only affects Visual Studio 2015, so for users who can update to Visual Studio 2017, that is indeed one way to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem of last xamarin release - It's page with [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1372)